# Change CSS Content from Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How could i change a background-color in a css file if I Scrolled down to a position of my website?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_pos > 260) {
            $('span[class="icon-bar"]').css('background-color', '#2CA8FF');
        } else {
            $('span[class="icon-bar"]').css('background-color', 'white');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.navbar - transparent.navbar - toggle.icon - bar, [class *= "navbar-ct"].navbar - toggle.icon - bar {
    background - color: white!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-ct-blue navbar-transparent navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

It works with other Content like an Image, but not with this. Why?

Comment: I'd really recommend to use a selector such as `$('nav .icon-bar')` or similar and save to a variable to avoid having jQuery search every single `<span>` in the whole `document` on each `scroll` event.

Comment: why are you trying to use .navbar-transparent class when you are setting it to have static color initially?? navbar-transparent will have its own bootstrap css properties that could possibly interfere your custom css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an `!important` declaration in your css file. This increases specificity, which could cause this:

```
.icon-bar {
    background-color: white !important; 
}
```

...to overpower this:

```
$('span[class="icon-bar"]').css('background-color', '#2CA8FF');
```

You can quickly try removing `!important` to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank's for your help. I dont now, why i didn't saw this ^^

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
$('span.icon-bar').css('background-color', 'white');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you have here is a problem of specificity against the styles you are trying to establish (because of Bootstrap). I have done what you want here several times, and normally I end writing !important after the color change. The normal solution I use is creating two clases:

```
.blue {
   background-color: #2CA8FF !important;
}

.white {
   background-color: #FFF !important;
}
```

And then assigning the classes instead of the styles in your jquery:

```
if(scroll_pos > 260) {
  $('span.icon-bar').addClass('blue');
} else {
  $('span.icon-bar').removeClass('blue');
}
```

Finally, as you can see, I haven't worked with .white. That is because I assign it directly to the elements in my html:

```
<span class="icon-bar" class="white"></span>
<span class="icon-bar" class="white"></span>
<span class="icon-bar" class="white"></span>
```

By default, all are white, and then, when you reach 260, they become blue because it is the last assigned class. It would be change your code a bit, but it has worked for me...